# Handling DateTimeOffset on the 28th of February

Tags: c#, unit-testing, date

I've got a test which is failing today (the 29th of May). It's a pretty straightforward test which verifies that something was purchased in the last 3 months, it goes along the lines of...

```
var purchaseDate = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMonths(-3); // returns the 28th of February
Assert.True(purchaseDate.AddMonths(3).Date >= DateTimeOffset.Now.Date) // 28th of February + 3 months is the 28th of May
```

This test fails only today.

I'm assuming this problem has been encountered plenty of times before, so, is there a way of handling it without switching the logic on the 29th of May?

Comment: It will also fail the 31st of july. Besides counting in days instead of counting in months, I have no idea what else you could do.

Comment: You're just lucky we're not using the Jewish calendar - month calculations are even worse there. "As a result, someone born in Adar during a non leap year would celebrate his birthday in Adar II during a leap year. However, someone born during either Adar in a leap year will celebrate his birthday during Adar in a non-leap year, except that someone born on 30 Adar I will celebrate his birthday on 1 Nisan in a non-leap year because Adar in a non-leap year has only 29 days."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your issue is more a design error. I would inject current date as an optional dependency to make sure I can test with any value I want.

Let's take an example with this small service you might have :
(Use whatever you like as DI)

```
public class MyService {

    // Private variables that will be initialized by constructor

    private readonly DateTimeOffset now;

    public MyService(MyFirstDependency dependency, DateTimeOffset now = DateTimeOffset.Now) {
         // Assign here your private variables
         this.now = now;
    }


    public void ValidateDateIsNotBefore3MonthsAgo(DateTimeOffset myDateToValidate) {
        if (!myDateToValidate.AddMonths(3).Date >= now.Date) {
             throw new WhateverYouWantException("Date is before 3 months ago");
        }
    }

}
```

That way, when you instantiate your tests, you can pass a DateTimeOffset with the value of your choice. You're not depending on the current date anymore.

**edit** : I forgot that you can also use [Fakes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx) to mock current date without having to modify your code, but it's [not available for every version of Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/3619488-provide-microsoft-fakes-with-all-visual-studio-edi)

Comment: That's something that people tend to miss when writing unit tests: The current date/time is an external dependency.